# How do I rotate a bitmap in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I know there are threads on this question already but the solutions seem to use methods from the Matrix class that don't seem to work anymore.  Even after imports the methods cannot be resolved.  I'm basically trying to rotate a bitmap 90 degrees because it comes out sideways when I take a picture vertically.  Here's my code for the activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        //Check that request code matches ours:
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_FULLSIZE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            //Get our saved file into a bitmap object:
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "image.jpg");
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
            intent.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());

            startActivity(intent);



        }
    }
```

Comment: check https://blahti.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/android-rotate-scale-bitmap/

Answer (score 23):

try this:

```
public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle)
{
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(angle);
      return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Here please pass your bitmap or in angle what you want to show your bitmap like 90 180 etc.it will change bitmap screen using postRotate() method of class Matrix and again create bitmap and revert you

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to rotate bitmap :D

```java
public Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap original, float degrees) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preRotate(degrees);
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(original, 0, 0, original.getWidth(), original.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        original.recycle();
        return rotatedBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextView to your layout and set the Bitmap to it

```
ImageView yourView = (ImageView)findViewById(imageviewid);
Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), 1000, 700);
yourView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Probably you can use `RotateAnimation` on the View (ImageView set to Bitmap) you want to Rotate, and do not forget to set the Animation to `fillAfter=true` and `duration=0`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="90"
  android:toDegrees="180"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:duration="0"
  android:startOffset="0"
/>
```

Now all you need is to inflate the animation to your View

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
yourView.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Or you can simply do this `yourView.setRotation(angle)` with `API >= 11`.

Comment: @ThanhLeTran Can you criticize my answer if it didn't work for you?