# How to most efficiently use and apply Android CameraX Image Analysis setTargetRotation

Tags: android, android-camerax

Similar to what is laid out in the [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze) I am initializing CameraX's Image Analysis use case with code:

```java
ImageAnalysis imageAnalysis =
    new ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(new Size(1280, 720))
        .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_90)
        .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
        .build();

imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, new ImageAnalysis.Analyzer() {
    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
        int rotationDegrees = image.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees();
            // insert your code here.
        }
    });


cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, imageAnalysis, preview);
```

I am trying to use [setTargetRotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#setTargetRotation(int)) method but I am not clear as to how I am supposed to apply this rotation to the output image as vaguely described in the docs:

> The rotation value of ImageInfo will be the rotation, which if **applied to the output image**, will make the image match target rotation specified here.

If I set a breakpoint in the `analyze()` method shown above, the image object does not get rotated when changing the `setTargetRotation` value, so I assume the docs are telling me to grab the orientation with [getTargerRotation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageAnalysis#getTargetRotation()) in the sense that these two pieces of code (builder vs analyzer) are coded separately and this information can be passed between the two without actually applying any rotation. Did I understand this correctly? This really doesn't make sense to me as the `setTargetResolution` method actually changes the size sent via the ImageProxy. I'd think `setTargetRotation` should also apply said rotation, but it appears not.

If my understanding is correct, is there an optimal efficient way to rotate these `ImageProxy` objects after entering the `analyze` method? Right now I'm doing it after converting to Bitmap via

```java
Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(someInutStream);

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(30);

Bitmap rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImg, 0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight(),
        matrix, true);
```

Above idea came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29982596/2760299), but I'd think this is not the most efficient way to do this. I'm sure I could also come up with a way to transpose the arrays, but this could get tedious and messy quickly. Isn't there any way to setup the ImageAnalysis Builder to send the rotated ImageProxy directly rather than having to make a bitmap of everything?

Answer (score 1):

> The rotation value of ImageInfo will be the rotation, which if applied
> to the output image, will make the image match target rotation
> specified here.

An example to understand the definition would be to assume the target rotation matches the device's orientation. Applying the returned rotation to the output image will result in the image being upright, i.e matching the device's orientation. So if the device is in its natural portrait position, the rotated output image will also be in that orientation.

Output image + Rotated by rotation value --> Upright output image

CameraX's documentation includes a section about rotations, since it can be a confusing topic. You can check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/orientation-rotation).

Going back to your question about `setTargetRotation` and the `ImageAnalysis` use case, it isn't meant to rotate the images passed to the `Analyzer`, but it should affect the rotation information of the images, i.e `ImageProxy.getImageInfo().getRotationDegrees()`. Transforming images (rotating, cropping, etc) can be an expensive operation, so CameraX does not perform any modification to the analysis frames, but it provides the required metadata to make sense of the output images, metadata that can then be used with image processors that analyze the frames.

If you need to rotate each analysis frame, using the `Bitmap` approach is one way, but it can be costly. Another more performant way may be to do it in native code.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Husayn Hakeem. Maybe asking how to rotate the ImageProxy is the wrong question. To avoid the expensive operations, ideally I'd want some API call that can format the array that backs the ImageProxy at creation similar to what appears to be going on with `setTargetResolution`. In that I mean, the `setTargetResolution` method appears to give control over the dimensions of this array whereas `setTargetRotation` does not. If I can `setTargetResolution(144,176)` rather than `setTargetResolution(176, 144)` I wouldn't really need to do any expensive "rotations".

Comment: I skimmed through the link you sent, and maybe I'm just not understanding Kotlin well enough, but I also don't see any actually implementation of "applying the rotation", just ways to identify which rotation should be applied. For Image Capture use cases, the Bitmap approach seems completely viable, but for Image Analysis and Image Preview, I'd think CameraX would have methods for applying the rotation no? Shouldn't there be some optimized native code for streaming images in a target orientation? Otherwise wouldn't we expect all but the original orientation of the array to run at slower fps?

Comment: Just to add some context to my particular use case. We have a pretrained TensorFlow Lite model that was trained on "portrait orientation" images. The `ImageProxy` given by the `analyze` method appears in a "landscape orientation" so we need to convert to Bitmap and rotate before feeding it to the model. This is obviously a big cut in the rate at which we can process images, so I was looking for a way to change the backing array shape rather than converting to bitmaps and rotating after the fact. The other option of course is to retrain the TF Lite model, but that is a VERY costly operation.

Comment: With regards to the example you gave for `setTargetResolution`, they do not affect the image's rotation, but just the size of the image, so instead of getting a portrait/tall image, you'd end up with a landscape/wide image, or vice versa.

Comment: "for Image Analysis and Image Preview, I'd think CameraX would have methods for applying the rotation". No, not at the moment, probably for the same reason I mentioned in my answer, because it's costly. This may well be added in the future though when CameraX will have stabilized its basic features/use cases.